# How to refer to the Label element in the ItemsControl to read data from it?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, itemscontrol

I need to read the id from the label and write it to a global variable to render the content on a separate page. But since this label is generated by ItemControls, I don't know how to refer to it. How can you implement separate pages that are automatically generated based on what the user clicked on?

Model global

```
public class global
    {
        public static int userid;
        public static string username;
        public static int catid;
    }
```

The markup of the page to navigate from

```
 <ItemsControl Name="icCatList">
                           <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                               <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                               </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                           </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                           <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                               <DataTemplate>
                                   <materialDesign:Card Margin="10 0 10 10 " Cursor="Hand" materialDesign:ElevationAssist.Elevation="Dp3" MouseDoubleClick="Cat_Click">
                                       <StackPanel Height="200" Width="200"> 
                                           <Image Source="F:\C#\Historical Saratov\Historical Saratov\App_Logo.png"/>
                                           <Label Content="{Binding ID}" Visibility="Hidden" Height="1" x:Name="Cat_Label"/>
                                           <TextBlock
                                               FontSize="18"
                                               FontWeight="Medium"
                                               Text="{Binding Cat_Name}"
                                           />
                                           <TextBlock
                                               FontSize="15"
                                               FontWeight="Regular"
                                               Text="{Binding Description}"
                                           />
                                       </StackPanel>
                                   </materialDesign:Card>
                               </DataTemplate>
                           </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                       </ItemsControl>
```

An example of a request based on which I tried to make a new page

```
InitializeComponent();
            DB db = new DB();

            string query = $"SELECT FirstName, LastName, ID, img FROM Login WHERE ID = {ID_Label.Content = global.userid}";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, db.GetConnection());
            db.openConnection();
            MySqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            try
            {
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    FN_Label.Content = myReader.GetString("FirstName");
                    LN_Label.Content = myReader.GetString("LastName");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
```

How do I try to read and find the data that I need to feed into the markup

```
List<CatModel> items = new List<CatModel>();
            DB db = new DB();
            db.openConnection();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand($"SELECT Cat_Name, Description FROM Category WHERE ID = {Cat_Label}", db.GetConnection());
            using (var rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    items.Add(new CatModel() {Cat_Name = rd.GetString(0),Description = rd.GetString(1)});
                }
            }
            icCatList.ItemsSource = items;
```

Comment: You do not take the value from the Label, but instead from the `ID` property of the appropriate `CatModel` object from the `items` collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an ItemContainerStyle with an EventSetter for e.g. the `MouseLeftButtonUp` event. In the event handler, you can access the clicked item via the `Content` property of the item container element (i.e. a ContentPresenter):

```
<ItemsControl Name="icCatList">
    ...
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonUp"
                         Handler="OnItemMouseLeftButtonUp"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

The event handler:

```
private void OnItemMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var content = (ContentPresenter)sender;
    var item = (CatModel)content.Content;
    var id = item.ID;
    Debug.WriteLine(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to use the [Model-View-ViewModel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern) (mvvm) pattern. With this approach you bind the [`ItemsSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) to an ObservableCollection in the viewModel file with all your items.

To handle selection you first need to use a control that support selection, for example a [listview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/listview-overview?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). You can then bind one of the Selected-properties, like [SelectedIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). From there it is a simple task of looking up the same object from the list. When this is done you also have the opportunity to update the model in any way you need.

Comment: It is also MVVM when you assign the ItemsSource property directly, instead of a applying a Binding.

Comment: If you bind `SelectedItem` you would directly get the selected CatModel instance. You can even do that in code behind without Binding like `var id = ((CatModel)icCatList.SelectedItem).ID;` - assuming that icCatList is a ListBox.

Comment: @Clemens Yes, you could do that. But I'm not sure I would call that MVVM, as far as I know, the point of the pattern is to avoid code behind as much as possible. I can't remember the exact difference between SelectedItem SelectedValue and SelectedIndex, but in my experience I usually run into some issue with the first two and end up using the index.

Comment: No, that is a misconception. MVVM is about separation of concerns. Whether there is code behind or not in the view is an implementation detail. You could even implement MVVM with a UI framework that has no data binding or declarative UI design. Advices like this make peope create more complex code than necessary when they try to implement convoluted things in XAML that would be three lines of code. We see this quite often here on SO.

Comment: Also note that it makes no sense to use an ObservableCollection when you only once create the source collection of an ItemsControl and later never add or remove elements.

Comment: And the issue *you* have run into with SelectedItem or SelectedValue do of course not indicate that these properties don't work, or are generally harder to use than SelectedIndex. Quite the opposite is true. SelectedItem or SelectedValue with SelectedValuePath="ID" is exactly what OP needs here.

Comment: Another thing: you would use ListView only when you would set its View property, e.g. to show a set of GridViewVolumns. With a single ItemTemplate, use the simpler ListBox, which is the base class of ListView.

Comment: ItemControl is not a list for me, it is a stack panel with a card, I thought I could get an ID from the label, but even what you are trying to help me I can’t use normally

Comment: @FainerGame StackPanel or not, it shows a list of items. The question is whether you want to have selection or not. Why not have a selected item that is indicated as such?

Comment: @Clemens I would disagree, from wikipedia: "MVVM was designed to remove virtually all GUI code ("code-behind") from the view layer". And I have had some memory leaks by binding to regular objects/lists, so as a rule I only bind to things that implement `INotify*`.

Comment: Well, that definition is too strict, maybe even wrong. As said, there is nothing that would keep you from implementing MVVM with a UI framework without XAML or data binding. I've sucessfully done it with Java Swing.

Comment: @Clemens That is fine, reasonable people can disagree.

Comment: ... and get into more trouble than necessary. Anyway, OP already implements MVVM according to your definition. There is XAML with Bindings. And all that is of course totally irrelevant for the problem that was asked for.

Answer (score -1):

In that line where you set the MouseDoubleClick Event which will be called when you double click on the specific MaterialCard "Cat_Click"

Just define in your Code Behind the following function

```
private void Cat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

var catId = sender.ID;
            DB db = new DB();
            db.openConnection();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand($"SELECT Cat_Name, Description FROM Category WHERE ID = {catId}", db.GetConnection());
            using (var rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    items.Add(new CatModel() {Cat_Name = rd.GetString(0),Description = rd.GetString(1)});
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Error = Cannot resolve symbol 'ID'